# How to save radio button values from html form into advanced custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, radio-button, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WordPress to develop a website and I am hitting a roadblock. How do I save the radio button values from an html form into an advanced custom field? The options that I have show up in the admin but the checked option is not picked. I want to change the color of an object according to the value picked. I am also getting the name and a brief description and that stores in the admin database no problem. I am using wp_insert_post() to submit the form because I want to display the results after submitting.

```
 if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
$current_post_author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$post_title = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['postTitle']);
$post_category = $_POST['review'];
$post_content = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['postContent']);
$postid = get_the_ID();
$postStarOne = $POST['rateOne'];
$postStarTwo = $POST['rateTwo'];
$postStarThree = $POST['rateThree'];
$postStarFour = $POST['rateFour'];
$postStarFive = $POST['rateFive'];

//$custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'new_post', true);

$category='review'; // category name for the post
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( $category ); // need the id of 'review' category
//If it doesn't exist create new 'review' category
if($cat_ID == 0) {
$cat_name = array('review' => $category);
wp_insert_category($cat_name); // add new category
}
//Get ID of category again incase a new one has been created
$new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($category);

$new_post = array(
      'ID' => '',
      'post_author' => $user->ID, 
      'tax_input' => array($category->taxonomy => array($category->review)),
      'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID),
      'post_content' => $post_content, 
      'post_title' => $post_title,
      'post_value' => $value,
      'post_type' => 'review',
      'post_status' => 'pending'
    );



 $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
 
 $field_key_one = 'group_5fb2ace92f979';
 $field_key_two = 'group_5fb2bcfd619dd';
 $field_key_three = 'group_5fb2be0da827d';
 $field_key_four = 'group_5fb2ace92f979';
 $field_key_five = 'group_5fb2bf62167a1';
 $value_one = $postStarOne;
 $value_two = $postStarTwo;
 $value_three = $postStarThree;
 $value_four = $postStarFour;
 $value_five = $postStarFive;
 update_field($field_key_one, $value_one, $post_id);
 update_field($field_key_two, $value_two, $post_id);
 update_field($field_key_three, $value_three, $post_id);
 update_field($field_key_four, $value_four, $post_id);
 update_field($field_key_five, $value_five, $post_id);

// This will redirect you to the newly created post
//$post = get_post($post_id);
wp_redirect($post_id->guid);
```

}

?>
This is the code that I am using to bring in the data from the user. The update field is what I thought was supposed to bring in the data from the post into the custom field but I must be using it the wrong way. I'm not worried about the validation yet. When I get it up and running then I can validate. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you running both `wp_update_post( $post_id );` and `$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);` ?

Comment: Anyway - `$post_id` looks to be empty on the functions for update `update_field($field_key_two, $value_two, $post_id);` etc. in the top you are setting `$postid` with `get_the_ID()` which will only work if you are in the loop, or on a page - but furthermore - `$postid` IS NOT THE SAME AS `$post_id`

Comment: If you want to save the fields on the new post, generated by `$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);` - Then you need to run that function BEFORE the `update_field` function, since you want to use that `$post_id`

Comment: also - regarding `wp_redirect($post->guid);`... where do you get `$post` from - does not look to be set anywhere

Comment: `wp_update_post( $post_id );` does not do anything here, since `$post_id` is not set, and it doesn't have any arguments

Comment: -Slender Thanks for taking the time to look over my issue. Took your advice and tried to run the update_field after the wp_insert_post($new_post). Still not saving the value of the radio buttons. I am on the home page but I have it set as a static home page.

Comment: I edited the code on here to show the changes. Thanks again Slender

Comment: Does it work now then?

Comment: No it still does not save the radio button selected value. I have to check the buttons in the admin before it takes affect. The name and the content pull in with no problem.